# A transformation from $e^{2\pi i nt}$ to $e^{2\pi i \lambda_nt}$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, harmonic-analysis

Let $e_n:=e^{2\pi i nt}$, $f \in L^2[0,1]$ and $a_n=\langle f, e_n\rangle$. Then the expansion $f =\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} a_n e_n$ is called the Fourier series representation of $f$, and $\left(\langle f, e_n\rangle \right)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ is the sequence of Fourier coefficients of $f$. The Fourier coefficients are 
$$a_n=\int_0^1 f(t)\, e^{-2\pi i nt}dt\, , \quad n\in\mathbb Z\, .$$
I'm considering a transformation such that
$$\mathcal T f:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \tilde a_n \tilde e_n\, , \quad \tilde a_n\neq a_n\, , \quad \tilde e_n=e^{2\pi i \lambda_nt}\quad \text{and} \quad \lambda_n\in\mathbb R\, .$$
The study of perturbed exponential system is not new but I was wondering if $\mathcal T$ is a particular kind of operator or transformation, already known in literature.

Comment: Your operator $\mathcal T$ is not well-defined. What is $\tilde a_n$?

Comment: Well this certainly won't work out the same as Fourier series (in terms of functional analytic properties) in general since you could just pick the $\lambda_n$ to be a subset of the integers but skipping some. I wonder if there are cases where it does.

Comment: You may be interested in “A Class of Nonharmonic Fourier Series” by Duffin and Schaeffer. They discuss certain sequences for which your modified exponentials form a “basis-like” object known as a frame.

Comment: Currently the dependence of the $\overline{a_n}$ on $f$ is not given. Assuming the frequencies $\lambda_{n}$ are well-spaced (for instance $\lambda_{n}$ lacunary, i.e. $\frac{\lambda_{n+1}}{\lambda_{n}}>q$, for some $q>1$) there are some similarities of these expansions to Fourier Series (Katznelson's classic book $\textit{An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis}$ treats integer lacunary series in Chapter V).